# Add <br> in between </span> and <span> using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I dynamically add a `<br>` tag after  and another  tag in HTML?

so my before code looks like this:

```
<span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
```

I want to look like this:

```
<span>Some Text</span><br><span>Another text</span>
```

There are a few span tags inside a `<div>` container, so is there a way to append all the span tags inside that div container so that all span tags have br tag one after another?

Note that `<span>` tag is produced and appended by a library, so there is no way i can change to a `<p>` tag or something else that has breakline.

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: <br> is deprecated, you should use css instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the span except the last since you don't need to place `br` tag after the last `span` and then append `br` tag after the element using [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method.

```js
// with pure css selector
$('.con > span:not(:last-of-type)').after('<br/>')

// or using jQuery :last
// $('.con span:not(:last)').after('<br/>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="con">
  <span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
  <span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
</div>
```

---

**Reference :**

1. [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
2. [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)
3. [`:last-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/)
4. [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
5. [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

---

**UPDATE :** With pure CSS you can use [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property.

```css
span {
 float:left;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
  <span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will use the first method you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method to add the html tag

```js
$('span').each(function(i, v) {
  $('<br/>').insertAfter($(this))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Some Text</span><span>Another text</span>
```

Comment: So, If i have more `span` tags in other portion of my code this each function will effect others   ?